# How to find negaive numbers from each line and print only once using shell script

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I want to find the negative numbers (same value) from each row of an input file.
If there is no negative numbers in a row it will print 0. If there is more than one occurrence of a negative number it will print the negative number once. For example 
the input file is (input.txt):

```
 1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 1       1      -1       0      -1       0       1       0       0
 1       1       0      -1       0       0       1       0      -1
 1       1       0       0      -1       0       0       0       0
```

The desired output is :

```
 0
-1
-1
-1
```

Currently I am using

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ /^-/) {printf "%s\n",$i}}' input.txt > output
```

But it does not produce the 0 in the 1st line and it prints all the -1s.
Is there a smart solution to this problem?

Comment: If last row in input is `1       1       0       0      -1       0       -5       0       -2` then what will be output?

Comment: no, it has only same kind of -ve numbers in each row. like -1 in the 2nd or 3rd or 4th row.

Comment: So it can have only `-1 or 0 or 1` in each cell?

Comment: What happens if there is just one negative number? Your desired output would seem to indicate that one is treated like many, though that's undefined in your description.

Comment: Yes. But it will be nice if the script is ignorant about the +ve numbers and sees only the -ve numbers which is same in each row (like -1).

Comment: @ghoti, Yes this script is not useful with the description. Thats why I am asking. If there is just one negative number in a row it will print that number (like row 4).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with simple pattern matching in bash, no need for awk.

```
while read line; do
  if [[ $line = *-1* ]]; then
    echo -1
  else
    echo 0
  fi
do < inputfile
```

Or shortened to a one-liner:

```
while read l; do [[ $l = *-1* ]] && echo -1 || echo 0; done < inputfile
```

Or sed could do this:

```
sed '/-/s/.*/-1/;/-/!s/.*/0/' inputfile
```

Or if you're willing to trade simplicity for performance:

```
sed -e '/-/s/.*/-1/;t' -e 's/.*/0/' inputfile
```

Comment: You can do this with simple pattern matching in awk, no need for bash :-).

Comment: Ah, Ed, I was hoping you were off today.  Ah well!  :-D  (Though, the bash one-liner is also a single pattern match, equivalent to your awk solution albeit a little more typing.)

Comment: Well then you bash guys would just breed out of control and THEN where would we be :-). The main issue with the bash loop, aside from the extra typing, is it'd be an order of magnitude slower than the awk or sed solutions. idk if that's an issue for the OP or not of course.

Comment: I just tested with 100k lines. Results were interesting. Bash is *not* in fact orders of magnitude slower. Result were: *awk=0.13s, sed=2.27s, bash=2.1s*. The sed solution gets slightly faster - 2.1s - if I make it single-match per my updated answer ... but according to these tests, awk (as you've used it) is clearly and undeniably the more performant solution.

Comment: I'm surprised sed is that slow but it looks like your data shows bash **is** an order of magnitude slower than awk: `awk=0.13s` vs `bash=2.1s`. I guess I won't assume decent performance from sed in future! Thanks for checking. For anyone else reading this and wanting to understand why a shell loop is so slow, see Stephane's answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '{p=0; for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) if ($i<0) {p=$i; break} print p}' file

0
-1
-1
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print (/-/?-1:0)}' file
0
-1
-1
-1
```

I assume that either:

1. you can't have a row with, say, `-2`s instead of `-1`s, or
2. if that does occur you still want `-1` output

since if it could happen that you have rows of `-2`s instead of `-1`s and want `-2` to be output in that case then that would have been a glaringly obvious thing to include in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description, you may use this:

```
 awk '/-/{print "-1"}!/-/{print "0"}' file
```